# Async Change Streams in MongoDB

Tags: c#, mongodb

I want to listen to a change stream for a collection, without blocking the thread.

In the code below the ForEachAsync will block forever, processing changes as they occur.

```
using (var cursor = await collection.WatchAsync())
{
    await cursor.ForEachAsync(change =>
    {
        // process change event
    });
}
```

I have tried removing "await" and storing the task in a variable instead, but no changes will be processed before i actually either await or .Wait() the task later.

I would expect that even though I don't await the task, the events would still be processed.

What can I do, so my entire program doesn't block to listen for changes?
I am considering wrapping the functionality in a new thread, but is that really necessary?

Comment: `I would expect that even though I don't await the task, the events would still be processed.` Your assumption is correct. Are you *absolutely sure* this isn't happening? MongoDB would have to be doing something *really weird* to prevent this.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

So, I figured out that the following works...

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Task watchTask = WatchCollection();

    // Do other stuff here, while watching...
}

private static async Task WatchCollection()
{
    using (var cursor = collection.Watch())
    {
        await cursor.ForEachAsync(change =>
        {
            // process change event
        });
    }
}
```

While I was attempting to do it like this, which doesn't work:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (var cursor = collection.Watch())
    {
        Task watchTask cursor.ForEachAsync(change =>
        {
            // process change event
        });
    }

    // Do other stuff here, while watching
}
```

So, the actual ForEachAsync task is awaited, while the outer Task which wraps the entire functionality is not awaited... I am either too tired or not familiar enough with Tasks to give a good explanation of why one works and the other doesn't.

Comment: The difference is when your `cursor` is disposed.

Comment: Oh god, you are right ... Ouch - I was too focused on the Tasks... Thanks, now I can sleep with a peaceful mind :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to comment (yet) so my feedback in the form of an answer:

You should be working with events (listeners, handlers) instead of await/async in this situation.
It's difficult to  elaborate on this without having more information on what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Well, basically I have a collection which somewhat rarely has new inserts (which is what i am watching for), so my application should be able to do other stuff and just react these inserts, when they occur and not be blocked, waiting for an insert.

Comment: Have you looked into using ObservableCollection? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: Im not sure how you mean? The problem I am having, is that the "// process change even"-code is not being executed, unless i explicitly await the Task given from ForEachAsync()